# Concatenating javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I'd like to set the variable `player` to the value "Leno Morales", which is also a value in my HTML table.

How do I concatenate the table value to my javascript?

Also, if I would like to change the `player` value based on the table value, how would I go about doing this?

At the moment, I have:

```
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';" 
    onclick="location.href='#individualwellness'">
    <td>
        <script>
            var player = Leno Morales
        </script>
    </td>
    <td>
        RA
    </td>
    <td>
        Injured
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td id="player">
    <script>
            var player = "Leno Morales";
            document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = player;
    </script> 
</td>
```

But, The best thing is to put the script in the end of HTML to make sure the table is already rendered by browser.

Comment: thanks! but if the value of `player` is different for each row of the data table, how should I go about coding the rest of the table?

Comment: answer from chandra is good to try, but make sure that you count correct number of `<td>` tags. Another workaround is the ID for each `<td>` should referring to the row number such as `player_0, player_1` and so on so you can use `document.getElementById("player_" + row)`

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the `<td>` tag where player name is to be inserted;

```
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';" onclick="location.href='#individualwellness'">
  <td id="playerValue">

  </td>
   <td>
     RA
  </td>
  <td>
     Injured
   </td>
```

Then you can set the value in  tag by:

```
<script>
     var player = Leno Morales;
     document.getElementById("playerValue") = player;
</script>
```

Or you can add value by counting `<td>` tag:

```
<script>
         var player = Leno Morales;
         document.getElementByTagNames('td')[0] = player;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ID` for the content form where you want to fetch the value like

```
<td id="playerValue">
    Leno Morales
</td>
```

Then to get the value inside a variable use the bellow code

```
var playerName=document.getElementById("playerValue").innerHTML;
```

### Synopsis

We use the first `ID` attribute in the `TD` tag for making it unique for easily locating. Then we use `innerHTML` function to bring the inner HTML text (i.e. Leno Morales) and then in the next code we use the value to place in a global variable (i.e. playerName). The variable have be previously declared to use it as globally or for locally it can the declared in the function as here.